# Getting Cocoapods installation error, while issuing command "npx react-native init MyProject"

Tags: ruby, react-native, rubygems, cocoapods, react-native-ios

I'm new to `react-native` I have read through the docs of getting started and installed cocoapods using the following command:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

this was successful. I'm using the below-mentioned environment:

```
Mac OS 10.14.6
Xcode 11.3.1
CLT 11.3.1
Ruby 2.6.5
Cocoapods 1.9.3
```

Now when I ran the command `npx react-native init MyProject` I'm getting the below log:

```
✔ Downloading template
✔ Copying template
✔ Processing template
✖ Installing CocoaPods dependencies (this may take a few minutes)
✖ Installing CocoaPods dependencies (this may take a few minutes)
error Error: Failed to install CocoaPods dependencies for the iOS project, which is required by this template.
Please try again manually: "cd ./MyProject/ios && pod install".
CocoaPods documentation: https://cocoapods.org/
```

Again, I tried the command `pod install` from inside the `ios` directory, got the following error:

```
Analyzing dependencies
Fetching podspec for `DoubleConversion` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `Folly` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec`
Fetching podspec for `glog` from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/glog.podspec`
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _ffi_prep_closure_loc
  Referenced from: /Users/soumisar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.13.1/lib/ffi_c.bundle
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libffi.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _ffi_prep_closure_loc
  Referenced from: /Users/soumisar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.13.1/lib/ffi_c.bundle
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libffi.dylib

Abort trap: 6
```

Please let me know, where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the solution:

The problem was this `glog` library in ruby(as mentioned in the error log above). Searched over the internet about the issue `Symbol not found: _ffi_prep_closure_loc`

This appears because in MacOS 10.14 the `ffi` library is an old one probably and it has to be updated. The command to install the latest ffi library is

`gem inst ffi -- --disable-system-libffi`

This command worked for me.

Or another solution would be to probably upgrade MacOS 10.15(Catalina)

For more details on this issue refer the below link

https://gitmemory.com/issue/ffi/ffi/791/645594873